# In Empathy IRC, how do I turn off the "joined" and "disconnected" messages?

Tags: empathy, irc

In Empathy IRC, how do I turn off the "joined" and "disconnected" messages?

Answer (score 5):

At the moment, there is no easy way to do this.

There is currently an open bug report regarding this issue: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=599453

In the meantime, I'd recommend switching to xchat or irssi, which are both great chat programs (xchat is GUI, and irssi is CLI), and are a lot less buggy than empathy. (unless you feel like testing/debugging/extending empathy)

Comment: Here's another vote for xchat.  It's a great IRC client, at least with respect to empathy.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer.  I do like the idea of having an integrated solution, so hopefully this is addressed soon.

Comment: And how would one kill JOINS and PARTS in xchat? In irssi, it's a matter of entering '/ignore * JOINS PARTS', but I haven't figured out a way to do this in xchat.

Answer (score 0):

I could suggest that you can clean the conversation. It do not prevent to have these messages, but can manually delete it.

1. Focus a conversation window (not account window).
2. Use the menu 'Conversation/Clean' or keyboard shortcut Ctrl+L.